# php page access. linked page

Tags: php, redirect, hosting, html

i got site that is contain a script the so installation success full and the admin and the content are runing well. 
but the main page to other pages such as videos , latest news , and other pages in the main menu. are riderect link www.hostname.com/videos  instead of videos.php.

acctual page is videos.php due to main menu linkink type the url is going to  www.hostname.com/videos

so the videos page not displayed and page not found error is occured. is their any short cut or edit htaccess file for this problem to when it goes www.hostname.com/videos make that link 
to videos.php that should be the correct page link

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running PHP on Apache, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule /video http://www.hostname.com/video.php
</IfModule>
```

**DISCLAIMER**

Untested and I am a n00b at rewriting urls.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot update the header link since you asked here...

Well, easy and lighter trick than mod_rewrite, working with standard Apache configuration : rename `videos.php` to `videos/index.php`

That is, if your script allows it and there is little to no refactoring.

Otherwise, RewriteRule is the (heavy) way to go, as @martincarlin87 said.